# How to change layout on button click in android app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I am new in Android so correct me if i am wrong. When another activity is opened, the first one is destroyed. So i have to pass all variables to the new activty if i don't want to lose the data. Or, can I run another not UI thread that manages my data?
Basically I need to change layout in my app on button click. Is there any way to do it within the same activity or i have to start another activity with the new layout?

Comment: You can pass data to another view by using *Intents* for example

Comment: And what about the activity? Have I to create a new one or can i change layout within the same activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one activity in your app and do what you want in fragments. Navigation is good tool to use for relating fragments to each other.

Answer (score 0):

well initially you can use a single activity and in that activity you can call multiple fragments as per your need,
and for the data you can use [MVVM](https://medium.com/upday-devs/android-architecture-patterns-part-3-model-view-viewmodel-e7eeee76b73b) architecture with [room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) architecture, it saves your lots of time and code.

and go with [navigation graph](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-design-graph) if you want a quick and easy implementation.

you can start all this with this [demo](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6014-the-navigation-architecture-component-tutorial-getting-started).

Comment: Thank you so much. I am still learning so I need as much resources as possible. I've never heard about MVVM and room architecture. I am going to read about this right now. I found the way to change the layout by using setcontentview method but in fact it is hard to manage all data etc. To many variables inside one activity that you don't need any more causes memory waste i think. And as i know mobile device apps must be as efficient as possible. Thank you again for usefull resources.

Comment: https://github.com/mitchtabian/Navigation-Components-Example and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEO2X5OU3MY check these for ref.